# A deadlock when use boost shared_mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have an very delicate deadlock bug when I use the `shared_ptr` with custom `Deleter` and `boost::share_mutex`:

First there is an WorkManager class to manage Work object:

```
class Work;
class WorkManager {
public:
    static WorkManager& instance() {
        static WorkManager instance;
        return instance;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Work> get(int id);
    std::shared_ptr<Work> create(int id);
    void update(unsigned int diff);
private:
    void _remove(int id, Work* t);
    WorkManager();
    mutable boost::shared_mutex _mutex;
    std::map<int, std::weak_ptr<Work>> _works;
};

void WorkManager::_remove(int id, Work* t)
{
    BOOST_ASSERT(t);
    std::lock_guard<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_mutex);
    _works.erase(id);
    delete t;
}

std::shared_ptr<Work> WorkManager::get(int id) {
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_mutex);
    auto iter = _works.find(id);
    if(iter == _works.end())
        return nullptr;
    return iter->second.lock();
}
std::shared_ptr<Work> WorkManager::create(int id) {
    Work* t = new Work(id);
    std::shared_ptr<Work> res;
    res.reset(t, std::bind(&WorkManager::_remove, this, t->id(), std::placeholders::_1));
    std::lock_guard<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_mutex);
    _works[res->id()] = res;
    return res;
}

void WorkManager::update(unsigned int diff) {
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_mutex);
    for(auto& t : _works)
    {
        if(std::shared_ptr<Work> work = t.second.lock())
            work->update(diff); 
    }
}
```

`WorkManager::update()` is triggered by a timer, called at a fixed interval like 100ms. Because `WorkManager` doesn't hold `shared_ptr<Work>` but only `weak_ptr<Work>`, after `work->update(diff);` returns the `work` may be destroyed because there may be no `shared_ptr<Work>` holding this particular `work` any more. Then the `WorkManager::_remove()` will be called via the custom deleter for the `shared_ptr<Work>`. Notice the update thread already hold a read lock, in `_remove()`, it needs to acquire a write lock. However it must release the read lock before it can acquire this write lock. So this thread is dead.

This problem means that I cannot write any Manager's function do things like:

```
boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_mutex);
for(auto& t : _works)
{
    if(std::shared_ptr<Work> w = t.second.lock())
        w->do_something();    
}
```

How to solve this? I figure out a solution is:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Work>> tmp;
{
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_mutex);
    for(auto& t : _works)
    {
        if(std::shared_ptr<Work> w = t.second.lock())
        {
            w->do_something();
            tmp.push_back(w); //prevent w destroy before the read lock unlock
        }   
    }
}
```

However this is error-prone, if someone forget this trick.

Comment: Your `_remove(int id, Work* t)` erases element `id` from the map and also `delete t`. Why do you combine these unrelated things in a single call?

Comment: _remove is called by shared_ptr's destructor, so it need do 2 things: 1. delete the pointer it managed. 2.remove the weak_ptr from WorkManager's std::map

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? What is the purpose (pre- and postconditions) of `WorkManager::create(int)`? Btw, it would greatly help if you could clean up the language (grammar) and use code highlighting in the text.

Comment: create just for show the shared_ptr custom deleter usage

Comment: The way you do multi-threading here is considered error-prone (as you just discovered) and obsolete. The modern way is message passing and no data sharing. What is your high-level problem?

Comment: multi-threading indeed error-prone but not all business can achieve by message passing, for example, high concurrency online game server